# How is Auto-Suggestions implemented in Android?

Tags: android

I am trying to see in android source code as how exactly auto-suggestion is implemented. For example, editable compose textview in messaging application shows suggestions when we start typing. I understand that input method displays the dictionary-based candidates. But, from where exactly it  fetches the suggestions ? Is there any dictionary database ?  I don't see any code where it fetches words from any source.

Comment: this isn't really the place to ask for tutorials, try google instead.  maybe "android auto-complete tutorial/sample" as keywords?

Comment: Please try to understand the question first. I am not asking for any tutorials. I am specifically asking about dictionary-based candidate view suggestions  and NOT AutoCompleteTextVIew. When I say source code, I mean Android repo code for internal implementation for the same. I beleive IME's InputMethodService displays the dictionary-based candidate view suggestions. But, how dictionary based suggestions are fetched by IME ?

Answer (score 0):

Try google first..:
http://blog.jamware.biz/2009/11/android-development-how-to-add-auto.html